# Conditional display of items on React-Autocomplete input

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, autocomplete, conditional-statements

I am new to React.js, but I am familiar with JavaScript and I am trying to build a form that autocompletes fields with users information stored in a JSON data file.

I found the react-autocomplete library that allows me to do just that. I managed to make it work and I'm happy with the overall, basic functionality. Now I'm trying to fine-tune the behavior so it fits my project needs.

Here's how I got it to work. I'm aware it might not be the most elegant way, but please keep in mind I just started fiddling with React in the last couple of days and most of the architecture and protocols are still super new to me.

The JSON user data array looks like this (I have several users stored):

```
[{
  "userid": "578",
  "firstName": "Alfie",
   "lastName": "Robles",
   "username": "anekdamian",
   "userLevel": "0",
   "projects": ""
 }]
```

`userLevel` is a numeric value that goes from 0 to 5.
And `projects` is the number of projects the user has assigned.

The JSON data gets imported into the userImport variable and then fed to the the userDataArray object:

```
let userImport = require('../cache/users.json');
this.state = {
      newProject: {
        address: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zip: '',
        contractor: '',
        projectManager: '',
        client: '',
        status: []       
      },
      statusOptions: ["Backlog", "Open", "In Progress", "Under Review"],
      touched: {
        address: false,
        city: false,
        state: false,
        zip: false,
        contractor: false,
        projectManager: false,
        client: false,
        status: false  
      },
      userDataArray: userImport
    };
```

And then, the data is pulled by the `Autocomplete` class into the `items` property:

```
<Autocomplete
  name={"client"}
  inputProps={{ placeholder:'Client'}}
  getItemValue={item => item.userid}
  items={this.state.userDataArray}
  renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
    <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}>
      {item.firstName}{' '}{item.lastName}{' ('}{item.username}{')'}
    </div>
  }
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
  onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}
/>{" "}
{/* Client of the Project*/}
```

So far so good! This implementation is working.

This is what it looks in action:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to make a conditional statement that will only autocomplete with users that have a `userLevel` lower than, say `3`.

I want to know how to do this type of conditional statement so that I can limit the suggestions displayed by the Autocomplete feature by specific criteria (number of projects, user level, etc.)

Since I'm this new to React, I'm not sure yet where and how you perform this type of conditional statements. 
I've been looking through the examples of the react-Autocomplete library and all the tutorials I could find regarding the topic, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

The other thing is that when a suggested user is selected, the value of the input is set to the `userid`, which is what I want. But is there a way that to the user, I still show a full name, instead? Just to keep the UX friendly.

Would I need to create a hidden input for that? Or maybe pass the ID value to a different key in the `this.state` array and leave the autocomplete one with the friendly version?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!
By using the javascript function that filters JSON objects in my `handleAutoComplete` function (please see my other answer for this reference), I was able to do the same when feeding the data to the `Autocomplete` component.

It looks like this now:

```
<Autocomplete
  inputProps={{placeholder:'Client', name:"client"}}
  getItemValue={item => item.userid}
  items={this.state.userDataArray.filter(obj => {
    return obj.userLevel <= '3'
  })}
  renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
    <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}>
      {item.firstName}{' '}{item.lastName}
    </div>
  }
  value={this.state.newProject.client}
  onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
  onSelect={value=> this.handleAutoComplete({value},'client')}
/>{" "}
{/* Client of the Project*/}
```

Notice how the `items` property now has an extra part that filters out the data.

So this answers my question and I hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution for the friendly display of the value.

I made a function that will handle the `onSelect` property of my `Autocomplete` component.

```
  handleAutoComplete(value,name){
      //alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.userDataArray), null, 4);
      let aquiredUserId = value.value;
      let findUser = this.state.userDataArray.filter(obj => {
        return obj.userid === aquiredUserId
      })
        this.setState(
          prevState => ({
            newProject: {
              ...prevState.newProject,
              [name]: findUser[0].firstName+' '+findUser[0].lastName,
              clientid: aquiredUserId,
            },
            touched: {
              ...this.state.touched,
              [name]: true
            }          
          }),
          () => console.log(this.state.newProject,this.state.touched)
        );  
  }
```

Here's the updated component:

```
<Autocomplete
  inputProps={{placeholder:'Client', name:"client"}}
  getItemValue={item => item.userid}
  items={this.state.userDataArray}
  renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
    <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}>
      {item.firstName}{' '}{item.lastName}
    </div>
  }
  value={this.state.newProject.client}
  onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
  onSelect={value=> this.handleAutoComplete({value},'client')}
/>{" "}
{/* Client of the Project*/}
```

So now my `Autocomplete` component sends the value to the function along with the name to be used as a key for it.

The function updates the value of the component with the First Name and Last Name of the user and also updates another value called `clientid` with the userid (which is the one that the backend actually cares about).

[image]

[image]

The only thing I'm still working on, is to make the `clientid` name be dynamically updated. So that it's something like `[name]+'id'` (this is not currently working, will update when I have figured it out).

Comment: I created a variable:
`let idName = name+'id';`
So now, the key for the id value is saved like this:
`[idName]: aquiredUserId,`